# How can I get count of rows for every week?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have select from table like:

```
SELECT DATEPART(WEEK, DayTime) as WeekNumber FROM dbo.Transactions
```

Result:

```
WeekNumber
1
1
1
2
2
3
4
4
5
4
5
3
```

How can I get count of rows for every number of week?

I need something like this:

```
WeekNumber    CountOfRows
1             3
2             2
3             2
4             3
5             1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `GROUP BY` week number and use `COUNT` function

```
SELECT DATEPART(WEEK, DayTime), COUNT(*) 
FROM dbo.Transactions
GROUP BY DATEPART(WEEK, DayTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEPART(WEEK, DayTime) as WeekNumber, COUNT(1) as CountOfRows  
FROM dbo.Transactions 
GROUP BY WeekNumber;
```

Comment: why downvote? Be a brave men a tell me what's wrong with that query?